# How do I properly setup Django translations?

Tags: python, django, django-translated-fields

When I try to `py manage.py makemessages --all`,I get this:

```
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1206, in \_gcd_import
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1178, in \_find_and_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1149, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 690, in \_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 940, in exec_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\\Users\\rodne\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site- packages\\translations\\apps.py", line 2, in \<module\>
from django.utils.translation import ugettex\`t_lazy as \_
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'    (C:\\Users\\rodne\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\translation_init_.py)
```

Super long error message.

I know Django recently changed the Translation so that you can no longer use ugettext into gettext as _ however that did nothing.